# Can we use Insert with When Matched Then Merge command in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

I want to use as below

```
WHEN   MATCHED  THEN    
       INSERT
```

But I'm getting error as below

> An action of type 'INSERT' is not allowed in the 'WHEN MATCHED' clause
>   of a MERGE statement.

How to make it work in SQL.

I need to use above to match my requirement.

Comment: What you're trying to do doesn't make sense. Why would you want to `INSERT` when you find a related row to update? That's just going to duplicate data; the error is stopping you from doing something foolish. What are you 8actually* trying to achieve here?

Comment: @chandrasekhar . . . I am voting to close as unclear what you are asking.  I recommend that you ask a *new* question.  Provide sample data, desired results, and an explanation of the logic you want to implement.